# Pause Powershell commands

Tags: powershell

i have written 2 simple commands that i am trying to tie together with the Start-sleep command

command 1

```
Enable-CsUser –Identity "user" –RegistrarPool  pool01.com  –SipAddressType EmailAddress
```

command 2

```
get-csuser "user"  | FL DisplayName,sipaddress | Out-file D:\lync_creation.txt -append
```

now each command works flawlessly on their own, but when i add `start-sleep -s 5`

```
Enable-CsUser –Identity "user" –RegistrarPool  pool01.west.com  –SipAddressType EmailAddress; Start-Sleep -S 5 | get-csuser "user"  | FL DisplayName,sipaddress | Out-file D:\lync_creation.txt -append
```

When i run this i get the following error

> Out-File : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Encoding'. The argument "Start-Sleep" does not belong to the set "unicode,utf7,utf8,utf32,ascii,bigendianunicode,default,oem" specified by the ValidateSet attribute. Supply an argument that is in the set and then try the command again
>   At line:1 char:179
>   + Enable-CsUser -Identity "kmarlowe" -RegistrarPool  pool01.west.com  -SipAddressType EmailAddress; Start-Sleep -S 5 | get-csuser "kmarlowe"  | FL DisplayName,sipaddress | Out-file <<<<  D:\lync_creation.txt -append Start-Sleep -s 5
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Out-File], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand

Comment: Tie together how? What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
nable-CsUser –Identity "user" –RegistrarPool  pool01.west.com  –SipAddressType EmailAddress; Start-Sleep -S 5; get-csuser "user"  | FL DisplayName,sipaddress | Out-file D:\lync_creation.txt -append
```

Comment: I want the 2 commands to run back to back automatically but there has to be a few second pause for the first command to finish before the second can kick off. i am using the Start-sleep to act as that pause allowing me to run both commands in 1 go

Comment: then, what I typed should work. It's 3 commands 1st one runs; sleep for 5 secs ; 2nd one runs.

Answer (score 3):

### Reason for problem

You are piping `Start-Sleep` into `Get-CSUser`, which will not work.

### Corrections

This is how your code should be:

```
Enable-CsUser -Ident "user" -RegistrarP pool01.com -SipAddr EmailAddress;
Sleep 5;
Get-CSUser "user" | FL DisplayName,sipaddress | Out-file D:\lync_creation.txt -a;
```

### Further advice ( Powershell Jobs )

You should learn up on Powershell **Jobs**.

See this example:

```
$Script = { 
    Enable-CsUser `
        -Ident "user" `
        -RegistrarP pool01.com `
        -SipAddr EmailAddress
}

$Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $script
Wait-Job -Id $Job.Id

Get-csuser "user" | FL DisplayName,sipaddress | Out-file D:\lync_creation.txt -a
```

This will wait until the job completes, instead of a random number of seconds.